# Where to find particular colour the theme?

Tags: theme

If you see in the image selected channel' Text is not at all readable.

I am aware of theme colour setting in Preferences panel. But i am not able to find the fallowing

So where do change the colour of background
And where do i change the colour of highlight text colour

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Channels were showing **Group colors** Over the default theme. Deselecting that option"Show Group Colors" from **View menu** brought back the readability.

[image]